# JSF APP with WebGL

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, webgl

My project is based on jsf & primefaces.

Recently there was a requirement from the customer to add 3D capabilities so I was thinking about WebGL.

My question is how can I use the data from the bean (server side)?
While via jsf API it's very simple I don’t know how to pass the values to the JS function.

Is it possible or perhaps there is some other why ?

Please advise since I am new to WebGL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions may be possible for you:

1. Embed JavaScript in JSF to bring the data from the bean to WebGL.
2. Create a web service that returns the data you need and call it from any ajax lib in JavaScript.

Comment: I prefer your first suggestion and actually I manage to embed a webgl script example inside a jsf file but I don’t know how to pass the bean data.

Any code example would be very helpful

Thanks